# Two trampolines - one renders - one does not. Why?

Tags: rendering, objects

So I'm struggling with these two trampolines. For some reason, the big one renders - the small one does not. And I can not figure out why. Except for the size they should be exactly the same.

[image]

Comment: Please don't make the question depend exclusively on users downloading your file. Use images to show the settings in the outliner, layers and render settings.

Comment: Duplicate of : [why does my object not show 
 up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) Reason 18

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions helped me. It was the object data duplication which needed to be set to none.